# How properly convert vector of numbers written as character into numeric type?

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a problem with my R code.
I want to convert numbers written as a characters in vector `powpow` into real numbers. As usually I used `as.numeric()` function, but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Here is my code, if anyone knows how to solve my problem, please write.
Thanks in advance.

The problematic part is start with comment "`# średnia i kwantyle powierzchni powiatów woj. wlkp.`"

```
############################################################

### Zadanie 1 ###
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
url <- "https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wojew%C3%B3dztwo_wielkopolskie"
website_html <- url %>% read_html()
tbls <- website_html %>% html_nodes("table")
tabele <- tbls[11] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
head(tabele)
tabele <- tabele[, -1]
head(tabele)
length(colnames(tabele))
nazwy <- colnames(tabele)
nazwy[1] <- 'powiat'
nazwy[2] <- 'siedziba'
nazwy[3] <- 'ludnosc'
nazwy[4] <- 'powierzchnia'
nazwy[5] <- 'gestosc'
nazwy[6] <- 'urbanizacja'
nazwy[7] <- 'wyd_budzet'
nazwy[8] <- 'doch_budzet'
nazwy[9] <- 'zadluzenie'
nazwy[10] <- 'stopa'
nazwy -> colnames(tabele)
head(tabele)
powiaty <- tabele # rm(tabele)


# średnia i kwantyle powierzchni powiatów woj. wlkp.
str(powiaty$powierzchnia)
powpow <- powiaty$powierzchnia
str(powpow)

for(i in 1:length(powpow))
{
  powpow[i] <- powpow[i] %>% gsub("\\,", "\\.", ., perl=TRUE) %>% as.numeric()
  print(str(powpow[i]))
}
```

What I want is a `powpow` vector of numbers, not characters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your global settings, you may need to replace `,` to `.` as decimal separators. An easy solution is `as.numeric()`:

```r
 # if your global settings accept "," as a decimal separator 
powpow_numeric <- as.numeric(powpow)

# if your global settings do NOT accept "," as a decimal separator
powpow_numeric <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", powpow, fixed = T))
```

There is also a way to change your global settings if the first option doesn't work, but I don't know it off the top of my head. Maybe someone else can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You already loaded the tidyverse package. you can use de `parse_number()` function from `readr` and get a numeric vector out of `powpow`.

```
parse_number(powpow)
```

> `as.numeric(powpow)` can do the same, but parse numbers will work in cases where the vector contains non numeric characters, like letters.

Anyway, base in what you have done I did as follow with all others variables that you will have to change:

```
powiaty <- powiaty %>%
    mutate(powierzchnia = parse_number(powierzchnia),
           urbanizacja = parse_number(urbanizacja),
           wyd_budzet = parse_number(wyd_budzet),
           doch_budzet = parse_number(doch_budzet),
           # in the case of "zadluzenie" and "stopa" we have to change ',' by dots before parsing
           zadluzenie = str_replace(zadluzenie, ",", "\\."),
           stopa = str_replace(stopa, ",", "\\."),
           zadluzenie = parse_number(zadluzenie),
           stopa = parse_number(stopa)) 

glimpse(powiaty)
```